# Correctly remove "dependent" elements from SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to find a solution how could I correctly remove kind of dependent data from the SQLite.

There are 2 tables with Many To Many relation and the "connector" table in between.
The example is quite classic: there's `DataTable` item which could contain multiple `TagTable` items. Also each `TagTable` item could belong to multiple `DataTable` items.

The structure is:

```
TagTable: id, name
DataTable: id, description, amount
ConnectorTable: id, tagTable_id, dataTable_id
```

`dataTable_id` is also marked as a foreign key.

`TagTable` record should **only** exist if there's **at least one** connection to the `DataTable`. So when I remove `DataTable` related `ConnectorTable` items will be removed automatically via foreign key. Then I need to check if `TagTable` items from removed `DataTable` item still have at least one connection (they are used by other `DataTable` items) and remove if they do not have any. I have no idea how to do it correctly.. So I'm looking for help. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your tables like this:

```
create table DataTable(id integer primary key, description text, amount real);

create table TagTable(id integer primary key, name text);

create table ConnectorTable(
  tagTable_id int references TagTable(id) on delete cascade, 
  dataTable_id int references DataTable(id) on delete cascade,
  primary key(tagTable_id, dataTable_id)
);
```

There is no need for an `id` in `ConnectorTable` since the combination of `tagTable_id` and `dataTable_id` may be the `primary key` of the table.

Now by turning `on` the foreign key support:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
```

you can insert rows in the table `ConnectorTable` with values for the 2 columns that already exist in the tables `DataTable` and `TagTable`.

If you delete a row from `DataTable` or `TagTable`, all rows in `ConnectorTable` that hold a reference to the deleted row will also be deleted.
This is what the action `on delete cascade` does.

So say you delete a row from `DataTable` and the rows from `ConnectorTable` that held a reference to the deleted `id` of `DataTable` are also deleted.
Now you may end up with rows in `TagTable` that are not referenced by any row in `ConnectorTable`, so you can do a cleanup with this query:

```
delete from TagTable
where not exists (select 1 from ConnectorTable c where c.tagTable_id = TagTable.id)
```

With similar actions, if you delete first a row from `TagTable` you can cleanup afterwards the table `DataTable`.